# How can I <iframe> Gmail?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome, gmail

I know that Gmail might put some security measures in place to prevent this, but I really need to put Gmail inside an  element.

The two following methods don't work:

```
<object type='text/html' data='http://mail.google.com/'></object>

<iframe src='http://mail.google.com/' frameborder=0 style='width:322px; height:480px;'></iframe>
```

Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 30):

You cannot. GMail, like most of Google's other web services, sets the HTTP header:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

which disallows their site from being framed by any site other than GMail itself.

Comment: but we can show google in iframe using this https://www.google.com/webhp?igu=1

Answer (score 11):

You would be better off using Google API.  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/

Although not a solution to your question I believe this is an appropriate alternative.