# how do i load gmail and google+ in an iframe or the equivilant.?

Tags: html, iframe, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I <iframe> Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325208/how-can-i-iframe-gmail)

I want to load gmail and google+ in iframes (or the equivalent)... so that i can use them in the same screen (large resolution).  Niether will load when put in standard iframe code.  How would one achieve this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325208/how-to-iframe-gmail