# How to display iframe on gmail body text

Tags: iframe, gmail

i am creating a Iframe body on gmail but is it's not working. in my html form it's working fine

my iframe url is

```
<iframe src="http://www.vivantabytaj.com/" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="My iFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="px" marginwidth="0px" height="900px" width="468px"></iframe>
```

Please help to display iframe on gmail body.

Comment: i measn to say it's is not displaying on mail when i send it to others

Comment: May be this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325208/how-can-i-iframe-gmail?rq=1