# Embed NEW Google sites to other web pages via iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embedded-resource

I hope you are having a great day!
I am trying to embed a NEW Google site into another web page. 
I am trying to use an iframe to embed the Google site but it doesn't work.

code line:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://sites.google.com/view/dm-viewer-samples" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

console error:

Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https://sites.google.com/s/1qcUAedTDdwcpfVAuSclwMF0K0bM2o2Lq/edit?userId%3D0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Answer (score 6):

As is said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3325268/9149444) post answer you can't include this site into an iframe due the HTTP header:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: Has this changed since you answered? Is there an option in Google sites?