# XSL not rendering the XML when loaded directly into the browser

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to link my XSL to my XML however when I load the XML page in Chrome or other web browsers I get a blank page.

I'm not sure exactly what is going wrong wit it.

Below is my XML

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="vaults.xsl"?>

<vaults xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vaults.xsd">

  <vault>
    <vaultname>Los Angeles Vault </vaultname>  
    <state>California</state>
    <location>Los Angeles (Cathedral)</location>
    <description>The Vault-Tec demonstration vault. It was not part of the experiment, and was the Master's vault under the Cathedral. </description>
    <fate> </fate>
    <appearance>Fallout</appearance>
   </vault> 
</vaults>
```

The following the is XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Vaults</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">vault</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="vaults/vault">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="vaultname" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="state" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="location" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="description" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="fate" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="appearance" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however when I load the XML page in Chrome or other web browsers I get a blank page.

If you load it from the local disk in Chrome, [you will get a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627265/ie9-and-chrome-not-rendering-xml-with-xsl-if-xml-is-local-and-xsl-is-on-remote-s), same in Internet Explorer. This is for security reasons.

I tested your XML and XSLT, stored both files locally and opened it in Firefox, and it "just worked":

[image]

Note, I would suggest making your stylesheet a bit easier to read and maintain. I.e., something along those lines (typically, using `xsl:apply-templates` with matching templates is easier to maintain and is better guarded against changes in the input):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Vaults</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">vault</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="vaults/vault" />
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="vault">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[parent::vault]">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested IE and chrome, never thought of firefox.