# XML using XSL won't output xml in Chrome/FF

Tags: xml, xslt

I cannot get the xsl rendered version to display anything other than a blank white page in Chrome/Firefox. Both of the pages live in QuickBase (in other words, I'm not testing this using local files which caused issues in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558160/xsl-not-working-in-google-chrome)).

If you access both the data xml and the xsl individually, they render fine. Ugh, help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- Generated by QuickBase Jan  5 2012 15:49:19 -->
<!-- Created Fri, 20 Jan 2012 02:01:56 -0500 -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="bgfn9a4ns?act=DBpage&amp;pagename=test.xsl"?>
<document>
 <dbinfo>
  <name>Contacts</name>
  <desc></desc>
 </dbinfo>
 <variables>
 </variables>
 <chdbids>
 </chdbids>
 <record>
  <name>Bob</name>
  <update_id>1327024286746</update_id>
 </record>
 <record>
  <name>Joe</name>
  <update_id>1327024284265</update_id>
 </record>
 <record>
  <name>John</name>
  <update_id>1327024292753</update_id>
 </record>
 <record>
  <name>Nate</name>
  <update_id>1327024289819</update_id>
 </record>
</document>
```

And here is the content of the XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <test>
   <xsl:for-each select="document/record">
    <xsl:attribute name="person"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </test>
  <FOO>BAR</FOO>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

The browsers are doing what is required of them, but there is no text to display in the output from your transformation, which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test person="Nate"/>
```

You have declared a single `<test>` element for output, and are looping over all document/record elements assigning a `person` attribute equal to the `<name>` element from the XML. An element cannot have multiple attributes with the same name, so it has just one equal to the last name found.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to see the rendered XML anyway? Why wouldn't it? And perhaps this is a poor example, but I've tried adding other test elements and it makes no difference, the page still renders a blank page.

Comment: @JoshuaMcGinnis You _are_ seeing the rendered XML.  Since it has no visible content, it looks like a blank page.

Comment: OK - I understand what you're saying, but even with a node of <TEST>something</TEST>, I should still see something! I don't!

Comment: I modified the code to include a node with some content. This evening, I will post the example on the web so that you can test. Thanks for your help so far Paul and Borodin.