# XML & XSLT Browser Issues

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, cross-browser

I'm learning XML & XSLT on an [online tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1eKCk1o5lo&feature=share&list=PLBF09D7B011F80BA7) & have run into a cross browser issue with one of the exampleS.

the XML file is running properly in firefox 19.0 & IE9 but not in Chrome Version 25.0.1364.97.

Any idea why this is happening or what I should do to avoid browser issues?

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="basic.xsl" ?>

<people>
    <husband employed = "Yes" >
        <name>Mark</name>
    <age>45</age>
    <wife>
        <wname>Janet</wname>
        <age>29</age>
    </wife>
    </husband>

    <husband employed = "No" >
        <name>Matt</name>
    <age>42</age>
    <wife>
        <wname>Annie</wname>
        <age>43</age>
    </wife>
    </husband>
</people>
```

& this is my basic.xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <table border="2px">
        <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="husband">
    <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The console readout from Chrome is:

> Unsafe attempt to load URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Ross/Desktop/XML%20Demos/basic.xsl from frame with
>   URL file:///C:/Users/Ross/Desktop/XML%20Demos/people_externalXSL.xml.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: Does the console of either failing browser show errors/info?

Comment: You may want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558160/xsl-not-working-in-google-chrome For what it's worth, it seems to be fine in IE9 for me.

Comment: How is it failing? Bad rendition, or errors? If so, what are the errors?

Comment: Thanks Ben, that seems to be it, worked when I ran Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` switch

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="husband/name">
    <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why? The original code is better, and correct. Is this a workaround for some known bug, or just random variation to suck it and see?