# What browsers support XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, browser, xslt-2.0

The Safari browser does not support XSLT 2.0 documents.

What browsers, if any, support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Do not use a browser to process your data.

Comment: @empo what tools do you normally use?

Comment: I use an XSLT processor like Saxon and MSXSL.

Comment: @empo i can't get to set up those things and there isn't an idiot's guide to it.. is there?

Comment: @empo actually this is a valid question if you are using browser side processing a la selenium

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Browsers do not yet support XSLT 2.0, natively.

- [Saxon 9 CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml) is a JavaScript-based XSLT 2.0 implementation.
- [Frameless](http://frameless.io/xslt/) is another, more light-weight XSLT 2.0 implementation in the browser, supporting large parts of the XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 functionality

See also:

- [How can I make XSLT work in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981524/how-can-i-make-xslt-work-in-chrome)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XSLT_2.0
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dareobasanjo/archive/2004/05/13/131166.aspx

Comment: An update to this: Saxon-CE is now a product, and provides client-side XSLT 2.0 processing on all major browsers. (It's written in Java, cross-compiled to Javascript using GWT).

Comment: A further update: Saxon-CE is now replaced by Saxon-JS, which is written in native Javascript rather than being cross-compiled from Java using GWT; it also supports most of XSLT 3.0.