# XSLT 2.0 functions don't work in Safari and Chrome?

Tags: xslt, google-chrome, safari

This is my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xml' href='/foo.xsl'?>
<document/>
```

This is `/foo.xsl`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:foo="foo"
  version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:function name="foo:const" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:text>ABC</xsl:text>
  </xsl:function>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="foo:const()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Works fine with Saxon 8.7 and produces `ABC`, as an output. But in Safari and in Chrome this document doesn't work (just an empty page with no error messages). What is it about? Safari and Chrome don't support XSL functions?

Comment: Are you by any chance accessing the local file system?

Comment: Everything works fine if I remove the `<xsl:function>`, so it's not about a possible file system problem you're referring to

Comment: @yegor256: None of the major browsers uses an XSLT 2.0 processor. However you may use SaxonCE with all of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [which browsers support XSLT 2.0 already?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282340/which-browsers-support-xslt-2-0-already)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, none of the browsers yet support XSLT 2.0 natively. I think they're all waiting for the others to move first.

Answer (score 1):

**Have you tried using [SaxonCE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/doc/contents.html)?**

This is Saxon 9.x implemented in Javascript -- it is reported to work with any of the five major browsers.

At the last Balisage conference Michael Kay (@Michael Kay ) demoed this working on his iPhone.

Comment: Very interesting link, thanks. Now it's a question of performance: who will do the transformation faster - Saxon on the server or SaxonCE inside the browser..

Comment: Of course @Michael Kay is the developer of Saxon and he can best answer such a question. I am not sure that there is a compelling argument in favor of either way. Javascript processing may be a tad slower, but happens on your box and thus network latency + server overload are eliminated.

Comment: The two architectures are just so different that you can't compare them on a single metric. Offloading work from the server to the client should certainly help server throughput, but whether it improves latency depends on how busy the server is. One of the performance issues with Saxon-CE is the delay when it's first downloaded to the browser (900Kb), especially on a slow connection; after that it's cached and very fast.