# Does xslt 2.0 work with major browsers

Tags: xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [which browsers support XSLT 2.0 already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282340/which-browsers-support-xslt-2-0-already)

I am doing reserach on xslt 2.0 and need to know what browsers it will work on. I have tried looking extensively and find old information about 2.0 not being compatible with many browsers. Is this still the case? I looked at "What is involved in upgrading from XSLT 1.0 to 2.0?"  but it does not mention if 2.0 is widely used and acceptable by major browsers currently. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

None of the major browsers includes an XSLT 2.0 implementation as standard, but the Saxon-CE product now provides a portable implementation that can be used with any browser that's enabled to run Javascript.