# Why does this XML file not display anything?

Tags: xml, xslt, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make XSLT work in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981524/how-can-i-make-xslt-work-in-chrome)

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalog.xsl"?>

<catalog>
    <album>
        <title>Exodus</title>
        <artist>Bob Marley</artist>
        <country>Jamaica</country>
        <price>19,99</price>
    </album>
    <album>
        <title>Black Album</title>
        <artist>Metallica</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <price>20,00</price>
    </album>
    <album>
        <title>Nevermind</title>
        <artist>Nirvana</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <price>22,00</price>
    </album>
</catalog>
```

which links to this XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My Catalog</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9ACD32">
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Artist</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/album">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
           </body>
       </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I open the XML file in a browser, I don't see anything being displayed. Since I copied from a tutorial as instructed, I'm not sure what went wrong here.  Do you have any clue in terms of what may be causing the lack of display?

Comment: It worked for me actually. Browser issue?

Comment: @Keyser: I tried this in Chrome. What did you try this in?

Comment: It views correctly in Internet Explorer 8 as well as Firefox 3.6, the only browsers I have available at the moment. are you sure you named your xsl file correctly? Its name, according to the XML-File has to be "catalog.xsl", are you sure you did that?

Comment: firefox for ubuntu canonical 1.0 (also says 12.0 above that)

Comment: even with an incorrectly named xsl file he'd see some text from the xml file

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6251757/306030) to a similar question.

Comment: @forty-two: Thanks. Using the answer, I verified this has been the case.

Comment: The problem is that Chrome as a security bug: Chrome doesn't honor the same-origin policy when a file is on the local hard drive. And rather than fix the broken same-origin policy, they just disabled support for xml+xslt. And because IE switched to Chromium, IE is also broken. The only option is to use Internet Explorer or Firefox - which [doesn't suffer from the same vulnerability.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4197)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on XSLT constraints of the browser you use you may see nothing.

I tested your files locally using Chrome 19.0.1084.46 and Firefox 3.6.22.

In Firefox I could view it with no problems, but in Chrome I saw nothing.

When I opened the console tab at developer tools in Chrome it show this message:

> Unsafe attempt to load URL
>   file:///temp/web/catalog.xsl from frame with URL
>   file:///temp/web/catalog.xml. Domains, protocols and
>   ports must match.

Then, I started my Tomcat and deployed the 2 files and when I accessed the xml from Chrome *voilà*, it shows everything as expected.

I'm guessing that you are accessing it using file:/// and this is related to this issue [Bug 397894](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=397894#c6)