# XSL shows the file in XML form. It doesn't show the HTML in any browser

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Why doesn't my browser show xsl as html when I try to view it?? It seems like everything is OK but I guess not. Another weird thing is that when i add the stylesheet paragraph the browser wont show anything if I try to view the XML file

**XML file: (test.xml)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test2.xsl"?>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>CBS Records</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1988</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Greatest Hits</title>
            <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>RCA</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1982</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Still got the blues</title>
            <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Virgin records</company>
            <price>10.20</price>
            <year>1990</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Eros</title>
            <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
            <country>EU</country>
            <company>BMG</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1997</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>One night only</title>
            <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Polydor</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1998</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
            <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>CBS</company>
            <price>8.10</price>
            <year>1973</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Maggie May</title>
            <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Pickwick</company>
            <price>8.50</price>
            <year>1990</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Romanza</title>
            <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
            <country>EU</country>
            <company>Polydor</company>
            <price>10.80</price>
            <year>1996</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
            <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Atlantic</company>
            <price>8.70</price>
            <year>1987</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Black angel</title>
            <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
            <country>EU</country>
            <company>Mega</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1995</year>
        </cd>
   </catalog>
```

**XSL file (test2.xsl)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**What it shows on the browser when XSL is used:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
<tr>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Code seems fine. I have tried it executing at http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog but how you are executing xsl file?

Comment: I tried to drag the file to the browser and also by opening the file with browser from the file location. Same thing happens with both

Comment: XML file doesn't show anything on the browser. when http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog is used to try it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are accessing .xml and .xsl files locally then it would not work with few browsers due to security restrictions. please check out here.
[How can I make XSLT work in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981524/how-can-i-make-xslt-work-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You are executing file in the wrong way. Please have a look at this article how you can run your xsl file [xsl_client](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp).

**Transforming XML to XHTML in the Browser**

Here is the source code needed to transform the XML file to XHTML on the client. you have to set `xml = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");` and `xsl = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");` :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```